# Help with my first Android UI

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having trouble developing the UI for my first lame "game".

Here is a screenshot.

[image: screen shot]

I'm using a LinearLayout that contains a TableLayout with TableRows.  It seems so tedious and hard to control the position of elements.

For example, to get things to line up, I've inserted empty TextViews to "push" other elements into place.

I've also added padding to the buttons to get them to be the size I want.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Be sure to post your XML code. As for adding empty TextViews - this is definitely bad practice (however, I will often use invisible Views when I need a horizontal space).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You definitely want to be using a [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) for this.

You would be able to specify where each button is in relation to other buttons.

Absolutely AVOID developing your UIs the way you are currently trying.  The TextViews will be different sizes for different distributions of Android, and will likely only look right on the device you tested them for.

EDIT:

If you need empty space, use the XML attribute `android:weightSum="x"`  in the parent view and  android:layout_weight="y" in the child.  This will make the child take up (y/x) of the space allotted to it in the layout_height and layout_width.

EDIT:

I think another good bit of advice for this would be to use individual layouts for things like your "direction" buttons.  You'll be able to handle where they are on the screen as a group, instead of having to move each individually.

Comment: isn't RelativeLayout just a view of elements from top to bottom?  Using RelativeLayout, how would you have something like my screen shot?  Like with text on the top, more text on the left, and button controls on the right? -Thanks!

Comment: You would use margins and padding, and layout each view relative to another :)

Comment: The visual editor in the newest SDK tools is excellent.  You can drag and drop elements where you want them and it automatically fills out all of the relativeLayout tags.  Also - as a new user, make sure to mark an answer to your question as answered - it allows other users to find the correct answer much quicker!

Comment: Pheonixblade9 - is this new SDK tool available for Eclispe?  That's what I am currently using. Thanks

Comment: If you downloaded Eclipse and installed the current SDK tools, then that's what you're using!  I believe it's Android Development Toolkit 12.x.  You can check with Eclipse -> Help -> Android button

Comment: Pheonixblade9 - I downloaded Eclipse and the Android SDK a few months ago. I'll have to check to see what version.  Thanks!

Comment: Pheonixblade9 - When you say use individual layouts, do you mean individual, relative layouts? For example a relative layout for one of each of my areas of the screen? (stats, buttons, text)....Thanks

Comment: It's your choice of layout to use.  You simply define it in XML and place it where you want.  If you're using a RelativeLayout, the order in XML doesn't matter, they will line up according to where you tell them to.

Answer (score 1):

You should use RelativeLayout to solve this problem. I've gone through a similar problem once...

I didn't use the the Android's default buttons, for I had my own images for the pressed and unpressed behaviors...

Let suppose you want to place the east "button". You could use a function like:

```
public void addEastImageView(RelativeLayout myBackgroundLayout, ImageView center, ImageView east, int leftPadding, int topPadding, int rightPadding, int bottomPadding){
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rightSide = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rightSide.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, center.getId());

        east.setPadding(leftPadding, topPadding, rightPadding, bottomPadding);
        myBackgroundLayout.addView(east, rightSide);
}
```

The ImageView called "center" would be the one you called "i" in your image. The padding parameters would allow you to control the distance between the ImageViews. You can create functions like this one to add the "west", "south" and "north" buttons also: you just have to change the parameter "RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF" to "RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF", "RelativeLayout.BELLOW" and "RelativeLayout.ABOVE" accordingly.

If you want some behavior for your ImageViews, you just have to set it in the [setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29). You can then change your ImageView's "image" with [setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29), for example, and set the others logic behaviors you want.

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score -2):

Use an AbsoluteLayout - it lets you state exactly where to put every element

http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-1-layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<Button
    android:layout_width="188px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_x="126px"
    android:layout_y="361px"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="113px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_x="12px"
    android:layout_y="361px"
    />
```

Comment: You do NOT want to use absolute layout for this unless you want to maintain one for each device and screen size.

Comment: Ouch - that would be a pain. Ya you would get it looking PERFECT on your AVD / Test device - but go try it out on another device.